# Key probability in which success occur in $7^{th}$ key

Tags: probability

A women has $10$ keys out of which one opens a lock. She tries the keys one after the another (keeping aside the failed ones) till she succeeds in opening the lock. What is the chance that the $7^{th}$ key works ?

Answer (score 3):

HINT: The probability that she picks one of the wrong keys first is $\frac9{10}$: $9$ of the $10$ keys are wrong. The probability that she picks a wrong key the second time is $\frac89$: $8$ of the remaining $9$ keys are wrong. Thus, the probability that she picks the wrong key on the first **and** second tries is $\frac9{10}\cdot\frac89$. You can continue reasoning in this fashion, remembering that on the $7$-th try she picks the **right** key instead of the wrong one, and you’ll arrive at the correct answer.

Alternatively, you can imagine that she tries all $10$ keys, simply making a record of which one opened the lock. Since she tries them in random order, the right one is equally likely to be in any of the $10$ positions in the sequence, so the probability that it’s in the $7$-th position is ... ?

Comment: @juantheron: You’re welcome.